# Join two lists with unequal length in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have 2 lists:

```
val list_1 = List((1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14))
val list_2 = List((1, 111), (2, 122), (3, 133), (4, 144), (1, 123), (2, 234))
```

I want to replace key in the second list as value of first list, resulting in a new list that looks like:

```
List ((11, 111), (12, 122), (13, 133), (14, 144), (11, 123), (12, 234))
```

This is my attempt:

```
object UniqueTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
     val l_1 = List((1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14))
     val l_2 = List((1, 111), (2,122), (3, 133), (4, 144), (1, 123), (2, 234))
     val l_3 = l_2.map(x => (f(x._1, l_1), x._2))
     print(l_3)

  }
  def f(i: Int, list: List[(Int, Int)]): Int = {
    for(pair <- list){
      if(i == pair._1){
        return pair._2
      }
    }
    return 0
  }
}
```

This results in:

```
((11, 111), (12, 122), (13, 133), (14, 144), (11, 123), (12, 234))
```

Is the program above a good way to do this? Are there built-in functions in Scala to handle this need, or another way to do this manipulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real over-complication you make is this line:

```
val l_3 = l_2.map(x => (f(x._1, l_1), x._2))
```

Your `f` function uses an imperative style to loop over a list to find a key. Any time you find yourself doing this, it's a good indication what you want is a [`map`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). By doing the `for` loop each time you're exploding the computational complexity: a map will allow you to fetch the corresponding value for a given key in `O(1)`. With a map you first convert your list, which is a key-value pair, to a datastructure explicit about supporting the key-value pair relationship.

Thus, the first thing you should do is build your map. Scala provides a really easy way to do this with [`toMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.collection.immutable.List):

```
val map_1 = list_1.toMap
```

Then it is just a matter of 'mapping':

```
val result = list_2.map { case (key, value) => map_1.getOrElse(key, 0), value) }
```

This takes each case in your `list_2`, matches the first value (`key`) to a key in your `map_1`, retrieves that value (or the default `0`) and puts as the first value in a key-value tuple.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
val map = l_1.toMap         // transform l_1 to a Map[Int, Int]
// for each (a, b) in l_2, retrieve the new value v of a and return (v, b)
val res = l_2.map { case (a, b) => (map.getOrElse(a, 0), b) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me difference between "{}" and "()" after .map? Sometimes, I can use round brackets after .map but for this one "()" will give me compiler error.

Comment: I used ``{}`` in that case so I can use pattern matching i.e ``case (a, b) => ...``

Comment: Applying `toMap` on list of tuples is risky: it can loose some tuples if there're duplicated first elements in the data set.

Comment: True, but then how to know which value to use anyway if there multiple ones? In the implementation proposed, it would pick the last one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic way is zipping them together and then transforming according to your needs:

```
(list_1 zip list_2) map { case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => (v1, v2) }
```

Comment: This does not work as intended when the lists have unequal length, try the example listed in the question.

Comment: Ah, I missed that lists are of different length. The approach can be adjusted, also it'll be not that elegant. For instance, if 1st list is shorter we can do `(list_1 ::: list_1 zip list_2)`.